# Recursive function return type error

Tags: java, recursion, biginteger

I wrote a recursive function taking an `int` as param, and return a `BigInteger`. Nothing seemed wrong, but one line is underlined in red.

I apologize if this is so obvious, but currently I can't wrap my head around this.

```
 public static BigInteger factorial(int a){
        BigInteger tot=BigInteger.valueOf(a);
        if(a>1)tot*=factorial(a-1);
        return tot;
    }
```

The line `if(a>1)tot*=(factorial(a-1));` is underlined in red.

Error:

> Required:BigInteger, Found:int

At the same time:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigInteger a=f(8);
}

public static BigInteger f(int a){
    BigInteger g=BigInteger.valueOf(a);
    return g;
}
```

...works.

It was from Intellij Idea. Is there some fundamental and important concept that I'm missing? Thank you.

**Edit**: So the answer, as user clebe45 explained, is that java **doesn't support operator overloading**, unlike c++, which is more familiar to me. If anyone found this as duplicating, please delete and I offer my apologies.

Comment: All basic math operations on `BigInteger`s must be done with the respective [class methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java does not support operator overloading, so you cannot use the multiplication `*` operator on it. Instead you should use:

> public BigInteger multiply(BigInteger val)

Answer (score 1):

`*=` does not work for BigInteger. Use [`multiply`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#multiply(java.math.BigInteger)) instead:

```
if (a > 1) tot = tot.multiply(factorial(a - 1));
```